# Diffrentiability and inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Assume that a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the conditions
>
> $$\sin x \leq f(x) \leq x$$
>
> for every $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $f(-x) = -f(x)$, when $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. Show that the function is differentiable at point $x = 0$ and that $f'(0) = 1$

We've been going through IVT, Rolle's theorem and MVT in lectures lately. I couldn't find a way to use any of those here, is there something Im missing or what's the correct approach here?

Answer (score 0):

For $h>0$ we have $\frac {f(0+h)-f(0)} h =\frac {f(h)} h$ and this lies between $\frac {\sin h} h$ and $1$. By Squeeze Theorem and the fact that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {\sin h} h =1$  it follows that $\frac {f(0+h)-f(0)} h \to 1$ as $h \to 0+$. I leave it to you [to use the fact that $f(-x)=f(x)$] to prove that the same thing is true when $h \to 0$ through negative values.